# How to find the name of a failing checkstyle rule

Tags: java, checkstyle

Checkstyle is balking at some code and I want to add a suppression rule.  How do I find the name of the rule that is failing so I can specifically suppress that rule for this section of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the command line version of Checkstyle, the easiest way would be to look at the XML output report. Use `-f xml` to tell Checkstyle to output XML. Violation messages in XML look like this:

```xml
<error line="0" severity="error" message="Missing package-info.java file."
    source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.JavadocPackageCheck"/>
```

So here, the check name for use by the suppression filter is `JavadocPackage`.

For manual lookup, you have some further options:

- You could manually go to [the list of available checks](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/checks.html) and search it for keywords from your violation message. (Thanks @crasp for pointing this out in the comments.)
- If you are using Eclipse, you can check the *"Include rule names in violation messages"* checkbox as described [here](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/advanced_preferences.html) to see the rule name in Eclipse.
- If you are using [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/), you can see the rule name by clicking on the issue.

Comment: Also have a look at the [available checks](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/availablechecks.html) for a quick search with keywords from your violation message. This is always the fastest way for me.

Comment: Thanks! I added your excellent suggestion to the answer above.